# Recording speech in uwp using naudio

Tags: uwp, windows-10, naudio, speech

I am trying to record user speech in uwp using naudio.Following is the code to initialize the naudio to capture and write to disk:

```
sourcestream = new WasapiCaptureRT();
sourcestream.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 1);

sourcestream.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
sourcestream.RecordingStopped += OnRecordingStopped;

sourcestream.StartRecording();

file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("audio.wav", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);

memorystream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

writer = new WaveFileWriterRT(memorystream, sourcestream.WaveFormat);

sourcestream.StartRecording();
```

But when execution comes to

```
memorystream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
```

an exception is thrown and execution goes to following code:

```
 DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };

    }
```

The exception in the code is

> Unsupported Wave Format

I tried to do the same in console application and everything worked fine. But when  I try to do it in UWP, the above error is shown.

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Unsupported Wave Format" is thrown by the following code snippet of the file [`WasapiCaptureRT.cs`](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio.Win8/Wave/WaveInputs/WasapiCaptureRT.cs) inside the [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) package.

```
if (!audioClient.IsFormatSupported(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, waveFormat))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported Wave Format");
}
```

So it seems like that the wave format you are providing by code line `sourcestream.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 1);` is not supported. A wave format like 44kHz may work fine.

```
sourcestream.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1);
```

Update:

> The file is saved but nothing is recorded.

Since you didn't provide the code for `OnDataAvailable` method, please try the followings:

```
 private async void btnrecord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     sourcestream = new WasapiCaptureRT();
     sourcestream.RecordingStopped += OnRecordingStopped;
     sourcestream.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
     file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("audio2.wav", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
     var radomsteam = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
     streamwriter = radomsteam.AsStreamForWrite(); ();
     sourcestream.StartRecording();
 }
 private void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
 { 
     writer = new WaveFileWriterRT(streamwriter, sourcestream.WaveFormat);
     writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
     writer.Flush();     
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by setting the sample rate as 48000. But somehow the audio recording doesn't work in uwp for windows 10. The file is saved but nothing is recorded.